# Get Current Folder URL using Client Context for JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, document-library, 2016, jsom

I am currently trying to retrieve the current URL of a document library using JavaScript.

My ultimate goal is to un-hide a web part when the user clicks a specific folder.

Right now,

My code so far:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadFolderView, "sp.js");

function unhidepart() {
    var unhideWP = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1");
    unhideWP.style.display="block";
}

function hidepart() {
    var hideWP = document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ1");
    hideWP.style.display="none";
}

function loadFolderView() {
    hidepart();

    var folderUrl = "https://example.com/sites/doclib/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fdoclib%2FFOLDER%20NAME";
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    ctx.load(site);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function () {
            var url = site.get_url();
            console.log(url);
            if (url == folderUrl) {
               unhidepart();
            }
        },
        function (sender, args) {
            console.log('error');
        });             

}
```

Right now it only logs `/sites/doclib` and I'm not sure how to get the full URL of the folder.

Any help or suggestions to make this easier would be very appreciated.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using? Where & how are you adding this code? Are you adding this code on document library view page using content editor/script editor web part?

Comment: 2016. Yes, using the script editor web part to add this to a document library view page.

Comment: You can get current URL in browser using `var pageUrl = window.location.href;`. does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the relative URL of current folder using:

```
ctx.rootFolder
```

**Example**:

```
var rootFolder = decodeURIComponent(ctx.rootFolder);
console.log(rootFolder);
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Note**: This is a default `ctx` variable loaded on SharePoint list/library view pages & not the `ctx` variable you defined in your code at `var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();`.

---

Also, You can get current URL in browser tab (includes complete URL with query parameters) using simple JavaScript:

```
var pageUrl = window.location.href;
console.log(pageUrl);
```

**Output**:

[image]

Further, you can split the URL & extract the necessary parts as per your requirements.